# Convert Jquery code into pure javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following Jquery code and I need to convert it into pure javascript code. Can any one please help me to convert it to javascript code

```
$( "#buttonOne" ).on('click', function() {
        $('#divOne').hide();
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what research efforts you have done. This isn't a code conversion service and what you are showing should be easy to research. Basic research is expected before asking questions here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be easy! Here you go:

```
document.getElementById("buttonOne").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("divOne").style.display = "none";
});
```